# Remove characters that matched regex on log4j2 event using replace parameter

Tags: regex, log4j2

Given this log event:

complete: task = { `'status' : 0`, 'task' : '{ 'id' : 9149263125397547267, 'process' : 'A-SIGN', 'in' : '/file/log4j-api-2.11.0.jar' }' }

How can I transform highlighted part into `status: 0` using regex?

So far I was able to get this part `complete: task = { 'status' : 0,` using the following code:

`/^(?:[^:]*[:]){2}[^:]*([,])/`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please also share the final string as an output you are assuming?

Comment: What is the code around it?

Comment: My expectation is to get `status: 0` on replace `$1 : S2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern: `'(status)'\s:\s(\d+)`

Replace: `$1 : $2`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nb53XO/1

Comment: Huh, interesting I can see Pattern working but Replace doesn't seem to work as expected. Still getting the whole line on substitution box.

Comment: Can you please share the link for the same? it will help me further

Comment: mmm... So I'm trying to configure a %replace parameter on log4j2 PatternLayout as follows: `<PatternLayout pattern="%replace{%m}{'(status)'\s:\s(\d+)}{$1:$2}%n" />`, my expectation is to get a log event like this: `status:0` but instead I'm getting: `complete: task = { 'status' : 0, 'task' : '{ 'id' : 9149263125397547267, 'process' : 'A-SIGN', 'in' : '/file/log4j-api-2.11.0.jar' }' }`

Comment: I actually tested on your Demo link at https://regex101.com/r/nb53XO/1.

Comment: Can you try this one: https://regex101.com/r/nb53XO/2